# Ember-cli project creation error

Tags: node.js, ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I am trying to create an ember project using ember-cli using this site http://www.ember-cli.com/

Command:

```
ember new my-new-app
```

Output:

```
version: 0.0.42
installing
  create .bowerrc
  create .editorconfig
  create .jshintrc
  create .travis.yml
  create Brocfile.js
  create README.md
  create app/app.js
  create app/components/.gitkeep
  create app/controllers/.gitkeep
  create app/helpers/.gitkeep
  create app/index.html
  create app/models/.gitkeep
  create app/router.js
  create app/routes/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/.gitkeep
  create app/styles/app.css
  create app/templates/.gitkeep
  create app/templates/application.hbs
  create app/templates/components/.gitkeep
  create app/views/.gitkeep
  create bower.json
  create config/environment.js
  create .gitignore
  create package.json
  create public/.gitkeep
  create public/crossdomain.xml
  create public/robots.txt
  create testem.json
  create tests/.jshintrc
  create tests/helpers/resolver.js
  create tests/helpers/start-app.js
  create tests/index.html
  create tests/test-helper.js
  create tests/unit/.gitkeep
  create vendor/.gitkeep
Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...bower ember-cli-shims#0.0.2 not-cached git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git#0.0.2
bower ember-cli-shims#0.0.2    resolve git://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims.git#0.0.2
bower ember-qunit-notifications#~0.0.3       not-cached git://github.com/dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications.git#~0.0.3
bower ember-qunit-notifications#~0.0.3          resolve git://github.com/dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications.git#~0.0.3
bower qunit#~1.12.0                          not-cached git://github.com/jquery/qunit.git#~1.12.0
bower qunit#~1.12.0                             resolve git://github.com/jquery/qunit.git#~1.12.0
bower ember-qunit#~0.1.8                     not-cached git://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit.git#~0.1.8
bower ember-qunit#~0.1.8                        resolve git://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit.git#~0.1.8
Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.bower ember-cli-shims#0.0.2                    download https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims/archive/0.0.2.tar.gz
bower ember-qunit-notifications#~0.0.3         download https://github.com/dockyard/ember-qunit-notifications/archive/v0.0.4.tar.gz
Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...bower qunit#~1.12.0                            download https://github.com/jquery/qunit/archive/v1.12.0.tar.gz
Installing packages for tooling via npmbower ember-qunit#~0.1.8                       download https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-qunit/archive/v0.1.8.tar.gz
Installing packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.Installing packages for tooling via npm..Installing packages for tooling via npm...Installing packages for tooling via npmInstalling packages for tooling via npm.ember-cli-qunit@0.0.5 postinstall: `bower install`
Exit status 1
Error: ember-cli-qunit@0.0.5 postinstall: `bower install`
Exit status 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\node\node_modules\ember-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Command:

```
cd my-new-app
```

Command:

```
ember server
```

Output:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'rsvp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\emberapp\my-new-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\ext
\promise.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I am behind a proxy. I have set npm proxy and it is working. Do I need to change any other configuration?